# can I clear current killring in zsh?

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

Yank doesn't clear the killring, so it gets cluttered after a while. Can I clear it?

I'm using Oh My Zsh.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The size of the kill ring is determined by the length of the [`killring`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#index-killring) array. This is 8 by default.

The variable is only available in zle widgets, so you can't manipulate it on the command line, you have to define a widget and invoke it either through a key binding or through `M-x`. Here's an example of a widget that blanks the killring.

```
set_killring_size () {
  local empty=
  if ((!$+NUMERIC)); then
    # Wipe killring and re-create it to its current size
    NUMERIC=$#killring
    killring=()
  fi
  if ((NUMERIC <= $#killring)); then
    # Truncate killring to the specified size
    killring=("${(@)killring[1,$NUMERIC]}")
  else
    # Grow killring to the specified size
    killring=("${(@)killring}" "${(@s:_:)${(l:$((NUMERIC-$#killring-1))::_:)empty}}")
  fi
}
zle -N set_killring_size set-killring-size
```

Call this widget with no argument to wipe the killring: `M-x set-killring-size RET`. Call it with a numeric prefix to set the killring size: `ESC 4 2 M-x set-killring-size RET`.